# Data from XSLT is not loaded

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Form application.
I Used XSLT to form the HTML page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Footballer's XSLT Demo</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h2>Footballer's Information</h2>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I write this code on load page:

```
namespace XSLT
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string MyXsltPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "1/footballers.xslt";
            XslCompiledTransform XSLTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            XSLTransform.Load(MyXsltPath);
        }
    }
}
```

But no information is displayed.
What I should do?

Comment: You are providing a transform, but where is your source data?  A transform is used to read XML and output it according to the xslt, but you seem to be lacking the xml source.

Comment: The previous commenter is right, even though I would have used a different wording: XSLT typically _transforms an XML input document_. Also, it seems to me you do not really invoke the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to load your xslt file,

```
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            System.IO.Stream xmlStream;
            System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform xsl = new System.Xml.Xsl.XslCompiledTransform();
            ASCIIEncoding enc = new ASCIIEncoding();
            System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

        String TransactionXML = "<xml><node></node></xml>";
        // Get Xsl
        xsl.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("footballers.xslt"));
        // Remove the utf encoding as it causes problems with the XPathDocument
        TransactionXML = TransactionXML.Replace("utf-32", "");
        TransactionXML = TransactionXML.Replace("utf-16", "");
        TransactionXML = TransactionXML.Replace("utf-8", "");
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(TransactionXML);

        // Get the bytes
        xmlStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(enc.GetBytes(xmlDoc.OuterXml), true);

        // Load Xpath document
        System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument xp = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument(xmlStream);

        // Perform Transform
        xsl.Transform(xp, null, writer);
        Response.Write(writer.ToString());
```